# Can't insert single quoted string value

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm using ef core (Npgsql) and insert values like this:

```
m_DbSet.Add(model);
m_Db.SaveChanges();
```

model has a string value

```
foo"bar'baz
```

and when I try to insert this string,
the string inserted like

```
foo"bar
```

I have tried to replace `'` to `\'` and `'` to `''`

data entered .cshtml form:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            @Html.MetroEditorFor(m => m.content, "Content", required: true, minLength: 3, placeHolder: "Please enter a content ...")
        </div>
</div>
```

after that all form convert to object

```
if (formValResult === true) {
        var fd = {};
        var keys = Object.keys(lastFormData);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var key = keys[i];
            var val = lastFormData[key];
            fd[key] = removeTags(val);
        }
        return fd;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

and post to controller, controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult Create(TEntity model)
{
   if (m_IsReadonly) return NotFound();

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
          m_DbSet.Add(model);
          m_Db.SaveChanges();
          return Json(new { success = true, message = "" });
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return ErrorResult("Eklenemedi !", ex);
      }
   }

   return ErrorResult("Eksik bilgi girdiniz !");
}
```

Debug view

[image: Debug view]

EF core query:

```
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p0='1633', @p1='DENEME' (Nullable = false), @p2='2023-08-13T10:40:00.0000000Z' (DbType = DateTime), @p3='2023-08-13T10:40:00.0000000Z' (DbType = DateTime), @p4='foo"bar' (Nullable = false), @p5='0', @p6='False', @p7='False', @p8='False', @p9=NULL (DbType = DateTime), @p10=NULL (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
      INSERT INTO t_app_duyurular (createdby, duyurubasligi, duyurubitistarihi, duyurubitiszamani, duyuruicerigi, duyurutipi, isdeleted, isenable, isloop, updatedat, updatedby)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)
      RETURNING id, createdat;
```

Comment: Could you please share a bit more code, it might be a problem at the upper layer or somewhere else.

Comment: Alright, what value does the `model` have before executing `m_DbSet.Add(model)`? Does it contain `'` before saving the `model` to the database?

Comment: The model value I see while debugging is "foo\"bar'baz"

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot illustrating this case under debug? Also, please add the SQL query generated by EF.

Comment: updated with debug and query

Comment: Thanks for the update. By SQL query I mean the query with data going to be inserted. I'd like to make sure the `foo\"bar'baz` string is passing to db.

Comment: Okey updated as you requested

Comment: Can you check your database directly: is the correct data inserted there, or is the issue with *displaying* the (correctly) stored data in your page?